# How to query Marklogic with punctuation-sensitve terms using JAVA?

Tags: java, json, marklogic, punctuation

I have the following info stored in Marklogic for the json files as follows.

```
1.json>> "dateSubmitted" : "2017/10/11 09:15:14"
2.json>> "dateSubmitted" : "2017/10/11 10:13:14"
3.json>> "dateSubmitted" : "2017/10/14 11:12:13"
```

My query term is:

```
String dateQuery = "2017/10/11";
```

I tried 2 methods and none seems to be working.

Method 1:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
QueryDefinition queryDef = qb.and(qb.word((qb.jsonProperty("dateSubmitted"),dateQuery)));
queryDef.setDirectory(DIRECTORY);
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryManager.search(queryDef, resultsHandle, start);
```

Method 2:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
String[] wordQueryOptions = {"punctuation-sensitive", "space-sensitive"};
QueryDefinition queryDef = qb.and(qb.word((qb.jsonProperty("dateSubmitted"),
                                      FragmentScope.DOCUMENTS,
                                      wordQueryOptions,100.0,dateQuery)));
queryDef.setDirectory(DIRECTORY);
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryManager.search(queryDef, resultsHandle, start);
```

**The expected result is to return only 1.json and 2.json.**

**However 3.json was also returned.**

Is there some settings I'm missing in my Marklogic admin to activate options or punctuation-sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Working with dates is often easier and more powerful if you index the property as a date. That way, you can do before and after matches on the date as well as sort on the date.

To index a property as a date, you can create a range index on the date. You can then use a range query on the date.

In MarkLogic 9, you can also use TDE to project rows from the documents with a column for the dates.

Hoping that helps,